# Change Authorize URL in Shopify for a Existing App

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I am in the process of updating my Shopify App with new Permissions. This means there is a change in the `authourize_url` which would show up the permissions window when trying to install an app. I have also changed the redirect URL of the App. The App is currently listed in Shopify, and there are accounts using the App.

1. How would this change affect the current App Installs?
2. How do I go about this without having any downtime or manually asking Customers to uninstall and reinstall the App again?
3. What is the best way to handle such scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You change the scopes. Your customers will therefore all have unauthorized oAuth tokens. The next time they try and use the App with the new scopes, your App will create a new oAuth token for their access as Shopify will prompt them to accept your new scopes.

It seems like pain, but it is the only way to go.

Comment: Thanks for answering David. My app inserts some code to the store and mostly runs in the background of store tracking purchases, user actions etc. Can i send a notification inside Shopify asking them to accept permissions as soon as i update the App?

Comment: You can export your customers from your partner dashboard entry for the App. Use that list to send an email to them I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the help David. This has been very helpful. Let me complete the process and then i can put down my observations here.